# Difference between thermodynamic density of states and single-particle density of states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

While reading Altland and Simons CMFT, I came across with two terms, one is Thermodynamic density of states, which is defined as

$\partial_{\mu} n = \frac{1}{L^d} \partial_{\mu} N$

The other is called single-particle density of states, which is defined as

$\nu = \frac{1}{L^d} \sum_a \delta( \epsilon_a - \mu) $

Now I have two questions,

1.The meaning of the single-particle density of states is self evident, but I don’t understand the meaning of doing derivative to the density w.r.t the chemical potential.

2. I don’t know under what conditions do these two concepts approximately agree with each other. In the book the authors say that the two will not equal if the inter-particle correlation is large.